# pass snowflake connection parameters in snowflake operator in airflow

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using AWS-managed apache airflow 2.0.2. I am passing the snowflake schema name through dag run config. I am able to use this schema name in the python operator but not in the snowflake operator.

Below is my code

```
def check_for_null_op(**kwargs):
    snowflake_schema_name = kwargs["database_schema"]
    print("printing schema name")
    print(snowflake_schema_name)
    dwh_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN,schema=snowflake_schema_name)
    result = dwh_hook.get_first("CALL test_proc()")
    print("printing results")
    print(result[0])
        /*some more code*/


check_for_null_op = PythonOperator(
    task_id="check_for_null_op",
    python_callable=check_for_null_op,
    op_kwargs={
        "database_schema": "{{ dag_run.conf['database_schema'] }}",
    }
)

test_sp = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id="test_sp",
    sql="CALL usp_check_for_null_op()",
    snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN,
    schema="{{ dag_run.conf['database_schema'] }}"
)
```

PythonOperator step is working but the SnowflakeOperator step is failing.
Below is the sample value of SNOWFLAKE_CONN

```
snowflake://username:password@abcd.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/?account=abcd&warehouse=WHS&database=DBS&region=us-east-1&role=ADD
```

Getting below error in test_sp task

```
SQL compilation error:Unknown function USP_CHECK_FOR_NULL_OP
```

But code is working if i pass hardcoded value in place of `{{ dag_run.conf['database_schema'] }}`

How to use the snowflake schema name in the SnowflakeOperator?

Comment: Can you add the error message/relevant logs?

Comment: Added error in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `SnowflakeOperator` the `schema` argument is not a templated field -- only `sql` is -- see [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8ae2bb9bfa8cfd62a8ae5f6edabce47800ccb140/airflow/providers/snowflake/operators/snowflake.py#L88). The operator is reading the Jinja expression for `schema` as the literal string "{{ dag_run.conf['database_schema'] }}".

However, something like this should work:

```py
test_sp = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id="test_sp",
    sql="CALL {{ dag_run.conf['database_schema'] }}.usp_check_for_null_op()",
    snowflake_conn_id=SNOWFLAKE_CONN,
)
```